# DateTime parsed from stopwatch's elapsed time always start at 12:00:00

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

I'm trying to parse the elapsed time from a stopwatch in to a specific format ==> hh:mm:ss.f as I am using it as a display on a time counter. This is what I try to do:

```
string counter = DateTime.Parse(_stopwatch.Elapsed.ToString()).ToString("hh:m:ss.f");
```

The problem is that instead of the counter display looking like this: xx:xx:xx.x it always displays as this: 12:xx:xx.x

Why does it always begin at 12?

I'd like to see something like this: 00:12:34.5 signifying that 12mins. 34s have elapsed instead of 12:12:34.5.

What am I missing here?

Thanks.

UPDATE

Fixed my own problem, did this:

> ```
> string formattedResult = _stopwatch.Elapsed.ToString(@"hh\:mm\:ss\.f");
> ```

Answer (score 3):

You're using `hh` which uses a 12-hour clock, rather than `HH` which uses a 24-hour clock.

Note that this has nothing to do with parsing the result from stopwach - you'll get the same if you write:

```
using System;

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        DateTime dateTime = new DateTime(2012, 2, 27, 0, 34, 45, 56);
        // Prints 12:34:45
        Console.WriteLine(dateTime.ToString("hh:mm:ss"));
    }
}
```

It's not clear why you're formatting the result of `Stopwatch.Elapsed` only to parse it again and then reformat it. Try to avoid extraneous string conversions. If you're using .NET 4, `TimeSpan` supports [standard](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee372286.aspx) and [custom](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee372287.aspx) formatting anyway.

Comment: Hi Jon, thanks for replying. I'm doing this in a WP7 app so I don't have access to .NET 4's custom string formatters. I tried doing _stopwatch.Elapsed.ToString(); but that formatted it down to milliseconds which I didn't want. Something like _stopwatch.Elapsed.ToString("HH:mm:ss[.f]"); didn't work either. 

I was looking specifically for deciseconds and hence @"hh\:mm\:ss\.f" did the trick for me.

Comment: @Cranialsurge: I still wouldn't convert it to a date/time. Just use custom format strings for each part of it. Fundamentally this *isn't* a date/time, and treating it as one is a bad idea. What would you want it to do if you ever got to above 24 hours, for example?

Comment: +Jon: Yup, I'm not converting it in to a DateTime anymore. All I need is that string I get in my update above. I will never go above 24 hours for this particular requirement but I understand your concern. Ideally all I was looking for was a string in that particular format for display purposes only. I could have stored _stopwatch.Elapsed directly if only the ToString() on it would accept something more than the standard 'c', 'g' and 'd' formatters TimeSpan offers.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following:

```
string formattedResult = _stopwatch.Elapsed.ToString(@"hh\:mm\:ss\.f");
```